# How to test an endpoint after facebook login with test user

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, endpoint, google-cloud-shell

I'm developing and app with facebook login but I want to check my node endpoint. I have create some users test and add the endpoint's url in Valid OAuth Redirect URIs settings.

The endpoint's code is simple:

```
router.get('/facebookToken', function (req,res) {

    logger.log('info',"********** USER LOG IN ********* ");
    logger.log('info','***Request: ',req.query);

});
```

I expected that when I click on Edit -> log in as this test user, I could see the logs and request values in cloud shell console, but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to try this get endpoint on mi server?

Answer (score 0):

“Log in as this test user” logs you in to facebook.com as this test user, it has nothing to do with login to your app.

After you logged in as the test user on Facebook, you need to visit your own app and click your login button there, to log into your app as the test user.